# Form submit without redirection and reloading

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I am new to HTML. I have written an app, which allows user to add data and it's a local application. I have used forms int this application and I am facing a problem when form submission happens. I don't want the page to navigate/redirect and even don't want the same page to reload. Currently it's reloading the page. Please let me know what stops redirecting/reloading this app. I don't want any php code, application needs to be pure HTML and JS only.
Below is the HTML app code.

```js
function addInfo() {
  var InfoForm = document.forms["InfoForm"];
  var trelem = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < InfoForm.length - 1; i++) {
    var tdelem = document.createElement("td");
    tdelem.innerHTML = InfoForm[i].value;
    trelem.appendChild(tdelem);
  }
  document.getElementById("current_table").appendChild(trelem);
  return false;
}

function done(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="current_div">
  <h2>Table Heading</h2> 
  <table border="1" id="current_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="input_div">
  <form name="InfoForm" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="done(e)">
    Name :
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="">
    <br>
    <br>Age :
    <input type="number" name="Age" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add_Info" onclick="addInfo()">
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** the right case to use a `<form>`. A `<form>` is used when you send via **GET** or **POST** method data to the **server**.

Therefore just use a `<button>` and two `<input>`.

It's easier to insert a row with [insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell).

**Complete example** :

```js
var nName = document.getElementById("nName");
var nAge = document.getElementById("nAge");
var btn = document.getElementById("addData");
var tbl = document.getElementById("myData");

function addData() {
  var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
  var d1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var d2 = row.insertCell(1);
  d1.innerHTML = nName.value;
  d2.innerHTML = nAge.value;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addData);
```

```css
table {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
#inputData > div {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#inputData > div > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myData"></tbody>
  <!-- Insert data -->
</table>
<div id="inputData">
  <div><span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" id="nName">
  </div>
  <div><span>Age:</span>
    <input type="number" id="nAge">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="addData">Add data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A **form submission** made a **GET**/**POST** request to the server. You can't use only JS for get data from a form submission.

If you don't want use server side language for some simple applications you can **make your own function** without really submit your form.

**Example without form**

```js
function gocalc()
{
  
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if(number>0 && number <11 && text !="")
  {
    for(var i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+"<p>"+text+"</p>";
    }
  }
  else
    alert("You must write some text and choose a number between 1 and 10");
    
}
```

```html
Choose a number between 1 and 10 <input type="number" max="10" id="number"> <br>
Write some text <input type="text" id="text"><br>
<button onclick="gocalc()">Ok</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

You can use **onsubmit** attribute and call your function. don't forget to **return false** for prevent the form submission.

**Example with form**

```js
function myfunction(myform)
{
  alert(myform.mytext.value);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return myfunction(this)">
  <input name="mytext" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```